# Swift: why the IBoutlet are not assigned (=) to their type instead they are just having a forced unwrapping type (!)

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I was wondering why IBoutlets like UILable's types are declared as:

`@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable: UILabel!`

instead of:
`@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable = UILabel()`

and what will happen if I make it:

`@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable = UILabel()`

Comment: UILable() you are assigning default label object for IBOUtlet. this will null and void and assign another ref when it connect to storyboard.

Comment: When it is like this `@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable: UILabel!`, it means this variable is of type `UILabel` and it definitely needs to be there (and the storyboard will create it for you, and indeed, it will be there, of course if you connected the IBOutlet correctly), but the second variant: `@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable = UILabel()`, is actually instantiation of a new UILabel, which will no longer point to the UILabel you have set up in your storyboard.

Comment: my question is how I'm able to use it and access the UILabel's properties, when it's not declared as = UIlabel()

Comment: It is marked as UILabel!. Its just implicitly-unwrapped optional. Why wouldn't you be able to access its properties?

Answer (score 3):

In the code below,

```
@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable: UILabel!
```

The above statement is an **implicitly-unwrapped optional**. This means that its value will be assigned later not just in the `init`.

Also, `@IBOutlet` will be assigned automatically once the outlets are connected to the storyboard after `init` and before `viewDidLoad()`.

On the other hand,

```
@IBoutlet weak var theNameOfThelable = UILabel()
```

Here you're assigning a brand new `UILabel()` instance to the `outlet`. This won't be connected to the `storyboard`.

In both the cases, `UILabel!` and `UILabel()` the assignment is different. You can still access the properties of `UILabel`. Only that if `UILabel!` is not connected before you're using it, the application will raise a *runtime exception*.